# phpmysql error - #1273 - #1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_general_ci'

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, collation

I have just installed PhpMyAdmin v4.1.5 English only

I have set it up to access 2 servers - the local one on my PC and the remote one on my server

All is fine for my local PC but when I log in to my remote server I get the message

Error

MySQL said:

> #1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_general_ci'

Searching the PhpMyAdmin code finds one reference to this in DatabaseInterface.class.php

```
        if (PMA_MYSQL_INT_VERSION >  50503) {
            $default_charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $default_collation = 'utf8mb4_general_ci';
        } else {
            $default_charset = 'utf8';
            $default_collation = 'utf8_general_ci';
        }
```

No idea what this is but it seems to be setting the default charset & collation wrongly

Comment: Does the local machine run Windows?

Comment: I am facing the same issue with linux.

Comment: I am having the same issue, but only in Firefox. Using Chrome works fine. Strange right?

Comment: yes that code is causing the issue. If I remove the if else condition and have just the code which is inside the else condition it works fine.

Comment: Here is the link to the issue in tracker: https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4236/

Answer (score 64):

[This solution worked for me](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/unknown-collation-utf8mb4_unicode_ci?replies=13#post-6884250)

1) Click the "Export" tab for the database

2) Click the "Custom" radio button

3) Go the section titled "Format-specific options" and change the dropdown for "Database system or older MySQL server to maximize output compatibility with:" from NONE to MYSQL40.

4) Scroll to the bottom and click "GO".

If it's related to wordpress, [more info](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/04/02/the-utf8mb4-upgrade/) on why it is happening.

Comment: Great solution. It helped me a lot.

Comment: Thank you very much for the useful tip.

Comment: Good one, Anyone knows how to do the same in mysql workbench

Answer (score 27):

You can fix this issue by deleting browser cookie from the begining of time. I have tried this and it is working fine for me.

To delete only cookies:

1. hold down ctrl+shift+delete
2. remove all check boxes except for cookies of course
3. use the drop down on top to select "from the beginning of time
4. click clear browsing data

Comment: PS. clearing cookie for one site works too , see Google Chrome: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?hl=en

Answer (score 10):

There are two steps to fix this.

First edit phpMyAdmin/libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php

Change:

```
    if (PMA_MYSQL_INT_VERSION >  50503) {
        $default_charset = 'utf8mb4';
        $default_collation = 'utf8mb4_general_ci';
    } else {
        $default_charset = 'utf8';
        $default_collation = 'utf8_general_ci';
    }
```

To:

```
    //if (PMA_MYSQL_INT_VERSION >  50503) {
    //    $default_charset = 'utf8mb4';
    //    $default_collation = 'utf8mb4_general_ci';
    //} else {
        $default_charset = 'utf8';
        $default_collation = 'utf8_general_ci';
    //}
```

Then delete this cookie from your browser "pma_collation_connection".
Or delete all Cookies.

Then restart your phpMyAdmin.

(It would be nice if phpMyAdmin allowed you to set the charset and collation per server in the config.inc.php)

Comment: Deleting the `pma_collation_connection` already made the error go away for me!

Answer (score 4):

When you export you use the compatibility system set to `MYSQL40`. Worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had read yesterday that the issue was fixed for someone when that person cleared cookies. I had tried that but it did not work for me.

Checking the following section in DatabaseInterface.class.php,

```
        define(
            'PMA_MYSQL_INT_VERSION',
            PMA_Util::cacheGet('PMA_MYSQL_INT_VERSION', true)
        );
```

I figured that somehow cache is the problem. So, I remembered that I was restarting the service instead of doing a `start` and `stop`.

```
# restart the service
systemd restart php-fpm

# start and stop the service
systemd stop php-fpm
systemd start php-fpm
```

Doing a `stop` followed by a `start` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: for the record clearing the cookie did worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Is your MySQL server version 5.5.3 or greater?

> The utf8mb4, utf16, and utf32 character sets were added in MySQL 5.5.3.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-sets.html

Comment: I am having the issue but the server is at 5.0.x.

Comment: 5.1.x, 5.0.x and below do not have the utf8mb4, utf16 and utf32 character sets.