# How to get xampp running an older version of mySQL and/or phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, web, phpmyadmin, xampp

I've recently been working on a website and unfortunately I realized that the server I am working with runs phpMyAdmin version 2.11.10 and MySQL version 5.0.67. While my xampp runs with phpMyAdmin version 4.1.6 and MySQL version 5.6.16. Is there any means by which I can run an older version of mySQL on my local computer (the xampp) as at the moment I am running into MySQl compatibility issues with some of my databases?

P.S would I also have to change the php version I am using?...My server is probably using a different version but I have not run into any php errors so far.

Update:Installing the older version gave me this error, #1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_general_ci'

for xampp version 1.6.8

Comment: [Here](http://code.iamkate.com/articles/xampp-version-history-apache-mysql-php/) is a list that details the versions of Apache, MySQL, and PHP included in each version of XAMPP. I think it could be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way around this would be a reinstall, but be sure to back up your database first, as well as make a copy  of your htdocs folder. Then dig around here for the right version of XAMPP:

http://www.oldapps.com/xampp.php?old_xampp=46

Comment: Unfortunately installing an older version of xampp gave me this error:
#1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_general_ci'

Comment: Hopefully this will solve the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190523/phpmysql-error-1273-1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-general-ci. You might find further guidance here: http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4236/. It seems MySQL 5.53 broke some old code. Might be worth trying a slightly earlier version of XAMPP.

Comment: Which file do I edit it says DatabaseInterface.class.php but I can't find the file location

Comment: You're running Windows right? Either way I think it's  phpmyadmin/libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php

Comment: yes and I can't find that file mentioned in the link you sent

Comment: Here's a link to a github branch with that php page: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php. Though I reckon you might be better off installing a version of xampp pre-MySQL 5.53.

Comment: ye I installed xampp MYSQL 5.0.67, unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: JUST UNINSTALLED AND INSTALLED FIVE TIMES AND IT WORKED