# Unable to open phpmyadmin in XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I installed XAMPP in my laptop when i tried to open phpmyadmin it gives me the error as follows

Error

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_general_ci'

Any suggestion why this error occurs?

Comment: This might help
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190523/phpmysql-error-1273-1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-general-ci

Comment: I had that error using Firefox, but not Chrome, with XAMPP 1.7.3. I fixed it cleaning the cookies.

Answer (score 1):

First Clear cookie

If error persists, try

Editing `phpMyAdmin/libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php`

Change

```
if (PMA_MYSQL_INT_VERSION >  50503) {
    $default_charset = 'utf8mb4';
    $default_collation = 'utf8mb4_general_ci';
} else {
    $default_charset = 'utf8';
    $default_collation = 'utf8_general_ci';
}
```

To

```
//if (PMA_MYSQL_INT_VERSION >  50503) {
//    $default_charset = 'utf8mb4';
//    $default_collation = 'utf8mb4_general_ci';
//} else {
    $default_charset = 'utf8';
    $default_collation = 'utf8_general_ci';
//}
```

Then restart Mysql.