# #1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' cPanel

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I have a WordPress database on my local machine that I want to transfer to a hosted phpMyAdmin on cPanel. However, when I try to import the database into the environment, I keep getting this error:

```
#1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
```

I have tried to Google around and the only solution I can find is this one [phpmysql error - #1273 - #1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_general_ci'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190523/phpmysql-error-1273-1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-general-ci) which as by now isn't much help. I have tried clearing the cookies but it still won't work. Please help!

Comment: What version of WordPress?  See https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/04/02/the-utf8mb4-upgrade/

Answer (score 109, accepted):

I had the same issue as all of our servers run older versions of MySQL. This can be solved by running a PHP script. Save this code to a file and run it entering the database name, user and password and it'll change the collation from `utf8mb4/utf8mb4_unicode_ci` to `utf8/utf8_general_ci`

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>DB-Convert</title>
  <style>
    body { font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Convert your Database to utf8_general_ci!</h1>

<form action="db-convert.php" method="post">
  dbname: <input type="text" name="dbname"><br>
  dbuser: <input type="text" name="dbuser"><br>
  dbpass: <input type="text" name="dbpassword"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
<?php
if ($_POST) {
  $dbname = $_POST['dbname'];
  $dbuser = $_POST['dbuser'];
  $dbpassword = $_POST['dbpassword'];

  $con = mysql_connect('localhost',$dbuser,$dbpassword);
  if(!$con) { echo "Cannot connect to the database ";die();}
  mysql_select_db($dbname);
  $result=mysql_query('show tables');
  while($tables = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          foreach ($tables as $key => $value) {
           mysql_query("ALTER TABLE $value CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci");
     }}
  echo "<script>alert('The collation of your database has been successfully changed!');</script>";
}

?>
```

Comment: This seems like overkill vs `mysqldump --compatible=mysql4`

Comment: For me it worked. Remember to name the file `db-convert.php`

Comment: If you make 'localhost' an input it's perfect.

Comment: `mysqldump --compatible=mysql4` or the answer below is a better option. I don't think it's a wise idea to change something like this on a live site. Better to export in the correct format, or if that's not an option, edit the exported file.

Comment: For me the command `mysqldump --compatible=no_table_options,mysql4` did the trick instead.

Comment: +1 I was able to use this answer's SQL query outside of the script context to "fix" each table and it worked for my problem. Then my table is the correct collation and I can import without having to remember to add flags

Comment: Check answer below so you can get a PHP7 version of this (new mysql library)

Answer (score 231):

[The technique in this post worked for me](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/unknown-collation-utf8mb4_unicode_ci?replies=19#post-6884250)

1) Click the "Export" tab for the database

2) Click the "Custom" radio button

3) Go the section titled "Format-specific options" and change the dropdown for "Database system or older MySQL server to maximize output compatibility with:" from NONE to MYSQL40.

4) Scroll to the bottom and click "GO".

I'm not certain if doing this causes any data loss, however in the one time I've tried it I did not notice any. Neither did anyone who responded in the forums linked to above.

**Edit 8/12/16** - I believe exporting a database in this way causes me to lose data saved in [Black Studio TinyMCE Visual Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/black-studio-tinymce-widget/) widgets, though I haven't ran multiple tests to confirm.

Comment: didn't work for me, i got the error #1231 - Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'

Comment: After multiple failed attempts at other solutions, this one worked perfectly on the first attempt.

Comment: Does NOT work with some new Wordpress sites.  When importing it on the other server, it generates this error on the very first table it tries to import (wp_commentmeta) #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1' at line 19

Comment: this didn't seem to make any difference for me, still getting the same error messages

Comment: you are the boss

Answer (score 187):

If you have already exported a `.sql` file, the best thing to do is to Find and Replace the following if you have them in your file:

- `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` to `utf8_unicode_ci`
- `utf8mb4` to `utf8`
- `utf8_unicode_520_ci` to `utf8_unicode_ci`

It will replace `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` to `utf8_unicode_ci`. Now you go to your phpMyAdmin cPanel and set the DB collation to `utf8_unicode_ci` through **Operations > Collation**.

If you are exporting to a `.sql`, it's better to change the format on how you're exporting the file. Check out [Evster's anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29974800) (it's in the same page as this)

Comment: it's working perfectly along with this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/30694416/1022726

Comment: For all you unix folks: `sed -i.bak s/utf8mb4/utf8/g FILE_NAME`. This will find all occurrences of `utf8mb4` in FILE_NAME and replace it with `utf8` while saving a copy of the original file to FILE_NAME.bak. You may need to tweak it to specify the exact coalition in your case but this is a start :)

Comment: I also had to replace: utf8_unicode_520_ci with: utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: Or via vi: `vi dump.sql` and then in via do this: `:%s/uf8mb4/utf8/g`.

Comment: and replace `utf8_0900_ai_ci` with `utf8_unicode_ci`

Answer (score 53):

i use this in linux :

```
sed -i 's/utf8mb4/utf8/g' your_file.sql
sed -i 's/utf8_unicode_ci/utf8_general_ci/g' your_file.sql
sed -i 's/utf8_unicode_520_ci/utf8_general_ci/g' your_file.sql
sed -i 's/utf8_0900_ai_ci/utf8_general_ci/g' your_file.sql
```

then restore your_file.sql

```
mysql -u yourdBUser -p yourdBPasswd yourdB < your_file.sql
```

Comment: There's a comment on another answer, which bears repeating here.  The OS X version of sed requires an extra argument after the -i flag.  So `sed -i '' ....` works.

Comment: I had to run this as well: `sed -i 's/utf8_0900_ai_ci/utf8_general_ci/g' your_file.sql`

Comment: The `-i` flag just mean replace in-place, so not to generate a new file

Comment: another OSX gotcha: prepending `sed` with encoding info like `LC_ALL=C sed …` fixes the byte sequence error, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916610/1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-unicode-ci-cpanel/42649372

Answer (score 30):

Wordpress 4.2 introduced support for "utf8mb4" character encoding for [security reasons](https://poststatus.com/the-trojan-emoji/), but only MySQL 5.5.3 and greater support it. The way the installer (and updater) handles this is that it checks your MySQL version and your database will be upgraded to utfmb4 *only if it's supported*.

This sounds great in theory but the problem (as you've discovered) is when you are migrating databases from a MySQL server that supports utf8mb4 to one that doesn't. While the other way around should work, it's basically a one-way operation.

As pointed out by Evster you *might* have success using PHPMYAdmin's "Export" feature. Use "*Export Method: Custom*" and for the "*Database system or older MySQL server to maximize output compatibility with:*" dropdown select  "*MYSQL 40*".

For a command line export using mysqldump. Have a look at the flag:

```
$ mysqldump --compatible=mysql4
```

Note: If there are any 4-byte characters in the database they will be corrupted.

Lastly, for anyone using the popular WP Migrate DB PRO plugin, [a user in this Wordpress.org thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/unknown-collation-utf8mb4_unicode_ci) reports that the migration is always handled properly but I wasn't able to find anything official.

> The WP Migrate DB plugin translates the database from one collation to the other when it moves 4.2 sites between hosts with pre- or post-5.5.3 MySQL

At this time, there doesn't appear to be a way to opt out of the database update. So if you are using a workflow where you are migrating a site from 
a server or localhost with MySQL > 5.5.3 to one that uses an older MySQL version you might be out of luck.

Comment: Changing compatibility to "MYSQL 40" totally worked for me.

Comment: If you then try and import the mysql4 compatible dump into a post v5.5.3 database (I'm using 5.5.28) then it fails because the script includes `TYPE=MyISAM` that was removed in v5.1. Do a search and replace with `ENGINE=MyISAM`. I couldn't see a way around this using the `mysqldump` output options.

Answer (score 27):

In my case it turns out my
new server was running `MySQL 5.5`,
old server was running `MySQL 5.6`.
So I got this error when trying to import the `.sql` file I'd exported from my old server.

MySQL 5.5 does not support `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`,  but
MySQL 5.6 does.

**Updating to `MySQL 5.6` on the new server solved collation the error !**

If you want to retain MySQL 5.5, you can:
- make a copy of your exported `.sql` file
- replace instances of `utf8mb4unicode520_ci` and `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`
...with `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`
- import your updated `.sql` file.

Comment: Yes - uploading to 5.6 is the simplest solution for this (and Ubuntu has a `mysql-server-5.6` package you can install that will remove 5.5 for you automatically).

Answer (score 16):

There is a line in wp-config.php:

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');
```

If you follow [Markouver's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30248919/2955384) / [Evster's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29974800/2955384) instructions, don't forget to change this line on production server to

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

in order to fix broken 4-byte characters

Comment: Also don't forget to modify `define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci');` as well. This helped for me.

Answer (score 11):

After the long time research i have found the solution for above:

1. Firstly you change the wp-config.php>  Database DB_CHARSET default
   to "utf8"
2. Click the "Export" tab for the database
3. Click the "Custom" radio button
4. Go the section titled "Format-specific options" and change the
       dropdown for "Database system or older MySQL server to maximize
       output compatibility with:" from NONE to MYSQL40.
5. Scroll to the bottom and click go

Then you are on.

Answer (score 7):

Seems like your host does not provide a MySQL-version which is capable to run tables with utf8mb4 collation.

The WordPress tables were changed to utf8mb4 with Version 4.2 (released on April, 23rd 2015) to support Emojis, but [you need MySQL 5.5.3 to use it.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.5/en/news-5-5-3.html) 5.5.3. is from March 2010, so it should normally be widely available. Cna you check if your hoster provides that version?

If not, and an upgrade is not possible, you might have to look out for another hoster to run the latest WordPress versions (and you should always do that for security reasons).

Comment: You can check your version of MySQL via command line with "mysql -V"

Answer (score 2):

So I solved in this way, from MySQL 5.6 to MySQL 5.5:

```
$ mysqldump -u username -p --compatible=mysql4 database_name > database_name.sql
$ sed -i 's/TYPE=InnoDB/ENGINE=InnoDB/g' database_name.sql
```

(Optional) Create a `.sql.gz` file:

```
$ gzip database_name.sql
```

---

### Explanation

```
$ mysqldump -u username -p --compatible=mysql4 database_name > database_name.sql
```

As explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30248919/3763649), this is just the equivalent of this options from phpMyAdmin: *"Database system or older MySQL server to maximize output compatibility with:" dropdown select "MYSQL 40"*.

```
$ sed -i 's/TYPE=InnoDB/ENGINE=InnoDB/g' database_name.sql
```

We needs this, to solve this issue:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 18: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=InnoDB' at line 9

Comment: Note if you're using OS X's version of sed: `$ sed -i'' 's/TYPE=InnoDB/ENGINE=InnoDB/g' database_name.sql` . 
If you want to keep a copy as `database_name.sql.bak` before the sed replace: `$ sed -i'bak' 's/TYPE=InnoDB/ENGINE=InnoDB/g' database_name.sql`

Comment: you can also inline `sed`.

Comment: Also if you're running mysqldump on MySQL 8 you need to use `--compatible=ansi` option

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced this issue. Solution which worked for me was opening local database with [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) and update [Encoding and Collation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv23D.png) to utf8/utf8_bin for each table before importing.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do is export your database to `.sql`, open it on Notepad++ and  "Search and Replace" the `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` to `utf8_unicode_ci` and also replace `utf8mb4` to `utf8`. Also don't forget to change the database collation to `utf8_unicode_ci` (Operations > Collation).

Answer (score 0):

open the sql file on Notepad++ and `ctrl + H.` 
Then you put "`utf8mb4`" on search and "`utf8`" on replace.
The issue will be fixed then.

Comment: It says "unknown collation utf8"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP7, then you would need a PHP script like this one in order to migrate your collation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>DB-Convert</title>
  <style>
    body { font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Convert your Database to utf8_general_ci!</h1>

<form action="db-convert.php" method="post">
  dbname: <input type="text" name="dbname"><br>
  dbuser: <input type="text" name="dbuser"><br>
  dbpass: <input type="text" name="dbpassword"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
<?php
if ($_POST) {
  $dbname = $_POST['dbname'];
  $dbuser = $_POST['dbuser'];
  $dbpassword = $_POST['dbpassword'];

  $mysqli = new mysqli('db',$dbuser,$dbpassword);
  if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli -> connect_error;
    exit();
  }
  $mysqli -> select_db($dbname);
  $result= $mysqli->query('show tables');
  while($tables = $result->fetch_array) {
          foreach ($tables as $key => $value) {
           $mysqli->query("ALTER TABLE $value CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci");
     }}
  echo "<script>alert('The collation of your database has been successfully changed!');</script>";
}

?>
```