# submit button has turned into a text box

Tags: php, sql, forms

http://lindsaymacvean.com/wuwo/activlist/sql_update.php

Im trying to implement a simple form from this question.

[#1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' Cpanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916610/1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-unicode-ci-cpanel)

I am seeing a textbox where the submit button should be and I don't know why?

UPDATE
For those of you who are seeing the code with spaces this is not what the original file shows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>DB-Convert</title>
  <style>
    body { font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;" }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Convert your Database to utf8_general_ci!</h1>

<form action="sql_update.php" method="POST">
  dbname: <input type="text" name="dbname"><br>
  dbuser: <input type="text" name="dbuser"><br>
  dbpass: <input type="text" name="dbpassword"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
version 1

</body>
</html>
<?php
if ($_POST) {
  $dbname = $_POST['dbname'];
  $dbuser = $_POST['dbuser'];
  $dbpassword = $_POST['dbpassword'];

  $con = mysql_connect('localhost',$dbuser,$dbpassword);
  if(!$con) { echo "Cannot connect to the database ";die();}
  mysql_select_db($dbname);
  $result=mysql_query('show tables');
  while($tables = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          foreach ($tables as $key => $value) {
           mysql_query("ALTER TABLE $value CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8   COLLATE utf8_general_ci");
     }}
  echo "<script>alert('The collation of your database has been successfully changed!');</script>";
}

?>
```

Comment: `type="submit"`. I.e. get rid of the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spacing between everything and it should work.

```
<form action="sql_update.php" method="POST">
  dbname: <input type="text" name="dbname"><br>
  dbuser: <input type="text" name="dbuser"><br>
  dbpass: <input type="text" name="dbpassword"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/w2c507ud/

Comment: I dont understand why that is happening on the front end because the original file is fine.

Comment: @lindsaymacvean does the original file have spacing? If it does, remove the spaces.

Comment: no the original file does not have spaces I will past the code into my question.

Comment: yeah it works locally. Weird. Anyone with any thoughts on this it would be really appreciated??

Answer (score 0):

try to change,

```
<input type=" submit ">
```

to

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

Comment: I have changed that and now it just looks like a text box with the word submit inside it.

Comment: Im thinking its something maybe todo with the way my server is serving the file or the permissions?

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in the

```
 body { font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;" }
```

Should be

```
body { font-family:"Courier New, Courier, monospace;" }
```