# MySQL Import error - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_520ci_'

Tags: mysql, wordpress, data-import

[Here is the Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBHtP.png) 
I can't import my sql file .

Comment: Please include the text of the error and some additional details. Otherwise this question is poor quality and will be closed. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your error is that your browser don't know what is `utf8mb4_unicode_520ci` what is the version of your mysql?

Answer (score 2):

You should change collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` to `utf8_general_ci`. One way to do this is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29939906/2780791).

You can also edit the sql file and replace `ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` with `ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci`

Answer (score 0):

open .sql file  and  rome

> INGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8193 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
>   COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

manually and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Before editing .sql file. Have a look at the version between both(backup and restore) of your MySQL. It was a version issue in my case. If you manage to get it on the same version, it solves the issue in most cases. If not then go for other recommended ways.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace charset "utf8mb4" with "utf8"
and COLLATE "utf8mb4_unicode_520ci" in your case with "utf8_general_ci".

You can achieve the replacement in MAC with below  sed command. In Linux remove ''.

```
sed -i '' s/utf8mb4_unicode_520ci/utf8_general_ci/g NEW-CLEANED-DUMP.sql
```

sed -i '' s/utf8mb4/utf8/g NEW-CLEANED-DUMP.sql