# How to take a dump from Mysql 8.0 into 5.7?

Tags: mysql

I would like to take a dump from Mysql 8.0.11 and restore it into 5.7.27.

When I tried to restore it I got the error:

> ERROR 1273 (HY000) at line 25: Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'

Then I tried to use the compatible flag to make it easier on an older MySQL DB.

```
mysqldump --compatible=mysql4 --add-drop-table -u r00t -h xxx.eu-north-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p radius_db > ~/radius.sql
```

But that doesn't seem to work either:

> mysqldump: Couldn't execute '/*!40100 SET @@SQL_MODE='MYSQL40' */':
>   Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'MYSQL40' (1231)

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Upvoted for the awesome title, I love me a little accidental humor on SO :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Import error - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4\_unicode\_520ci\_'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41401436/mysql-import-error-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-unicode-520ci)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply put, use as a DEFAULT "**utf8**" and as COLLATE "**utf8_general_ci**".

One way to solve your problem is to change in your import .sql-Files from

- "**utf8mb4**" to "**utf8**"
- and "**utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci**" (or something else) to "**utf8_general_ci**"

**Hint**: Don't forget to backup your files just in case ;-)

Go to your (.sql) import files and do these changes.
From:

```
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

to:

```
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

Reimport again.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up changing all occurrences of `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ` to `utf8mb4_general_ci ` and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the next code to move your database from mysql 8.x to mysql 5.x.

```
mysqldump db > db.sql

sed -i s/utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci/utf8mb4_general_ci/g db.sql

mysql db < db.sql
```

db is your database name