# Error when importing to server

Tags: mysql

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_layerslider` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT '',
  `slug` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT '',
  `data` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `date_c` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `date_m` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `schedule_start` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `schedule_end` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `flag_hidden` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `flag_deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci'

When attempting to import a database. I'm very new to all of this, hoping someone can assist in simple terms for me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916610/1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-unicode-ci-cpanel

Answer (score 0):

could be you are using  an oldeversion of mysql db .. and the collate you need  is not avialable  .. you could use try alter the table  or change the collate

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_layerslider` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, as I'm new to this would I need to add the code:
'ALTER TABLE' '`wp_layerslider`' 'CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci'

and where would I add it?