# Unknown collation 1273 error MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I am migrating a wordpress site but when I try to import the database I get the following error:

> 1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci'

I think that it is caused because of the different version of MySQL, is that correct? How to fix the code below? This is how every table is created.

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_commentmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `comment_id` (`comment_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before posting a question, you are expected to put some effort in to solve it yourself. A simple search would have turned up the following question which has a number of potential solutions: [#1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' Cpanel
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916610/1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-unicode-ci-cpanel)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4\_unicode\_ci' Cpanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916610/1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-unicode-ci-cpanel)

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this by finding

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

in your .sql file, and swapping it with

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: From your answer, I replaced  utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci  with  utf8_general_ci  and then  utf8mb4  with  utf8  and it worked nicely. thanks.

Comment: @Dr.AaronDishno Welcome

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Linux server, you can simply use the following command to change SQL file before import it into the database:

```
sudo sed -i 's/utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci/utf8mb4_unicode_ci/g' your_sql_file.sql
```

Do not forget to replace `your_sql_file.sql` with path and name of your own file.