# Getting "Swiss Standard German, ss" character with UTF-8 collation

Tags: character-encoding, collation

After searching in the archives I found a few resources that recommended replacing the character encoding ([#1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' Cpanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916610/1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-unicode-ci-cpanel)).

This is what my collation was (CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;) and this is what I converted it to (CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci). I also changed the collation in phpMyAdmin to utf8_unicode_ci. HTML meta charset is UTF-8. The problem persists. Issue can be viewed here by looking for words that have 'ss' in them:  http://photonew.rasdesignmedia.com/about-roger-aguirre-smith/

Further testing shows that the problem does not exist with iOS. It persists in Chrome, Safari, Opera and Firefox.

Comment: Did you just want to place a link to your site?

Answer (score 0):

The problem resided in my CSS and had nothing to do with collation at any level. Here is a link to more detail of what I found regarding CSS font-feature-settings: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/281076/126173