# wordpress, unknown collation #224 in table wp_posts.frm

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am connecting my wp database via sqlpro and while checking my tables I get unknown collation #224 error. I have tried [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916610/1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-unicode-ci-cpanel) with no luck.

My wp site gives db connection error. Is there anything I can do to restrore my database?

Answer (score -1):

it is local server or hosting, where is your WP ?

Comment: It is on hosting