# Wordpress Database import error : Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' #1273

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am transferring my website from one hosting server to other, while importing the database to new server getting this error.

`import error : Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' #1273`

I also searched google and found that it's the issue in the mysql version with wordpress version 4.2, mysql version should be greater than 5.3.

There is no issue for the cookies.

Is it possible to do this by another way as I cannot change the server configuration.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190523/phpmysql-error-1273-1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-general-ci

Comment: hey Thanks for the reply. 
----------
Go the section titled "Format-specific options" and change the dropdown for "Database system or older MySQL server to maximize output compatibility with:" from NONE to MYSQL40.
----------

This worked for me.