# Wordpress site migration - Collation error

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to migrate my wordpress website via [Akeeba Backup For Wordpress](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup-wordpress.html). Unfortunately, as soon as I try to install the database, I get the following error:

```
   Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci'
```

The database collation is utf8mb4_unicide_ci and the MySQL version is 5.5.52.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190523/phpmysql-error-1273-1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-general-ci) that one has to change the database system from "None" to "MYSQL40". But there is no such setting in the Akeeba control panel.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32105)

It seems that collation is only available for mySql 5.6+. I guess you are on 5.6-.

Comment: I guess you are right, everything below 5.6 is problematic right at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You *might* be able to open your SQL dump file in a text editor and do a search for "utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci" and replace it with "utf8mb4_general_ci".

Re-save your dump as a different file, and give the import a try. It's possible this might screw up some complex character encoding, but it's worth trying this simple fix first.

Comment: Well, the problem is that I don't know where Akeeba stores the DB-dump.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Akeeba, you could try the Duplicator plug-in to effect the migration. I've been using it for a long time and it works like a charm:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

(After installing the plug-in, generate a Duplicator package via the plug-in's menu on wp-admin dashboad.

Once the package is generated, download the two package files - installer.php and the archive/zip file - to some folder on your PC. Next, upload these two files to the live site's web root where you wish to create/migrate the site. Next, open the following link in your browser:

http://{your_domain}/installer.php

and follow on-screen instructions. Your site should get created and everything should work fine.)

Comment: Sounds very interesting and I'll definitely give it a try, thank you!