# error #1046 when importing database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

when importing database, this is the error that occurs:

```
-- Database: `maha associates`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `wp_commentmeta`
--

CREATE TABLE `wp_commentmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `comment_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
MySQL said: Documentation
```

> 1046 - No database selected

how do i solve that??

Comment: Why tagged as php ?

Comment: sorry its at phpmyadmin>import then that error pops up

Answer (score 1):

Put this at the beginning of your file

```
USE yourdatabasename;
```

This defines the target database for mysql.

Comment: Yes it tells mysql to import it to the database "yourdatabasename"

Comment: it brings the same error but now with this line at the bottom:

#1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci'

Comment: -- Table structure for table `wp_commentmeta`
--

CREATE TABLE `wp_commentmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `comment_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
MySQL said: Documentation

#1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci'

Comment: For your second question have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190523/phpmysql-error-1273-1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-general-c

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you did the export from, choose "Custom - display all possible options"
Under "Format-specific options:"
Under "Database system or older MySQL server to maximize output compatibility with:"
Choose: MYSQL323